# REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a query which I was using in an Access database to match a field. The rows I wish to retrieve have a field which contains a sequence of characters in two possible forms (case-insensitive):

- `*PO12345`, 5 digits preceded by `*PO`, or
- `PO12345`, 5 digits preceded by `PO`.

In Access I achieved this with:

```
WHERE MyField LIKE '*PO#####*'
```

I have tried to replicate the query for use in an Oracle database:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MyField, '/\*+PO[\d]{5}/i')
```

However, it doesn't return anything. I have tinkered with the Regex slightly, such as placing brackets around `PO`, but to no avail. To my knowledge what I have written is correct.

Comment: There are five digits.

Comment: I think it should be `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MyField, '\*?PO\d{6}')`

Comment: I've just edited the question - I should've said 5 digits in the question. Pardon my haste.

Comment: If there are more than 5 digits, should the string still match the regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex `\*+PO[\d]{5}` is wrong. There shouldn't be `+` after `\*` as it's optional.

Using `?` like this `/\*?PO\d{5}/i` solves the problem.

Use `i` (case insensitive) as parameter like this: `REGEXP_LIKE (MyField, '^\*?PO\d{5}$', 'i');`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS4pZ9/3)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[Read REGEXP_LIKE documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, sorry I don't know why I was using `+` instead of `?`; however, it still returns nothing.

Comment: I would add start and end anchors too, so `REGEXP_LIKE(myfield, '^\*?PO\d{5}$', 'i')` - otherwise the regex will match strings like `ABCD*PO1234567890`, etc.

Comment: @DavidFaber `*PO12345` is within the field somewhere; it does not make up the whole field.

Comment: @noob thank you - it works now. I initially missed one of your more subtle changes: `[\d]` to `\d`.

Comment: @monster, thanks for the correction - I did not read the entire question carefully. If that be the case then the `*` can be omitted entirely in the regex since `PO\d{5}` matches `*PO12345`

Comment: @DavidFaber: `PO` does match `*PO12345`, but `*PO` is also a valid match and leaving out `*` will not match `*PO12345` if `^` and `$` is used.